# What is the use of tensorflow backend utilities?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In order to create custom loss functions, I have seen many people use backend functionality from tensorflow.
For example if we want to create custom loss function that takes `y_true` and `y_pred` as input and compute square of difference between them. ie `MSE`

**Code:**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras.backend as kb
import numpy as np

y_true = np.random.uniform(0,1,(100,))
y_pred = np.random.uniform(0,1,(100,))

def custom_mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.math.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_true - y_pred))

def custom_loss(y_actual,y_pred):
    custom_loss=kb.mean(kb.square(y_actual-y_pred))
    return custom_loss

print(custom_mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred))
print(custom_loss(y_true, y_pred))
```

**Output:**

```
tf.Tensor(0.15846486198115287, shape=(), dtype=float64)
tf.Tensor(0.15846486198115287, shape=(), dtype=float64)
```

Why is the loss function created using backend utilities instead of normal tensorflow utilities?
What is the use of backend utilities except for using the function that are not present in normal tensorflow?

Answer (score 0):

`tf.keras.backend` comes from the time where `keras` was a standalone library that was able to use different libraries such as TensorFlow, Theano or CNTK as a "backend", i.e as the librbary that would perform the computations. The goal was to able to write the same `keras` code that would be able to run on different libraries.

Or, if I quote the documentation of keras 2.3:

> #### What is a "backend"?
>
> Keras is a model-level library, providing high-level building blocks for developing deep learning models. It does not handle itself low-level operations such as tensor products, convolutions and so on. Instead, it relies on a specialized, well-optimized tensor manipulation library to do so, serving as the "backend engine" of Keras. Rather than picking one single tensor library and making the implementation of Keras tied to that library, Keras handles the problem in a modular way, and several different backend engines can be plugged seamlessly into Keras.

The `backend` module was then written to handle a generic API for different libraries that might have different names and slightly different behaviour for the same operations.

As of today (2021-03-26), keras 2.4 does not support multiples backends anymore. The `tf.keras.backend` module of TensorFlow 2.4 contains a limited amount of functions, so it is encouraged to migrate from `tf.keras.backend` to "normal" TensorFlow functions.

Comment: Does this mean going forward there is no use of backend utilities and in future the backed utilities may get merged/removed into/from tensorflow?

Comment: @AniketBote you might be interested in reading [about this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/releases/tag/2.3.0)